# Output is off in for loop

Tags: java, operators

Okay, so I'm trying to learn how to use the % operator, and I made a simple program that prints out [0] in a loop, and every ten times it goes to the next line, but the first time it doesn't.

this is the output:

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

this is what the output should be:

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

And this is the code:

```
public class RemainderLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            System.out.print("[0]");

            if((i%10) == 0 && i > 0)
                System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, since you are printing the newline AFTER you print the [0], when you get to the 11th item, you print it before the newline, when you want to print it after, because its the 11th.

try this instead

```
public class Loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            if((i%10 == 0) && i > 0)
                System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.print("[0]");
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1; i < 51; i++){
            System.out.print("[0]");

            if((i%10 == 0) && i > 0)
                System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you're starting your counter, `i`, at zero, not at one. Do a few loops by hand, and you'll soon see the error. Any more than that, and I'd give the answer away.

Comment: That's good advice in general..should always run it through in your head (or on paper) if there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

public class RemainderLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++){
            System.out.print("[0]");

```
        if((i%10) == 0 && i > 0)
            System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

}